# phpmyadmin 4.1.4 issues with usergroups

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just updated to phpMyAdmin 4.1.4 and now it is giving me this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] ...    not OK [ Documentation ]
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] ...   not OK [ Documentation ]
Configurable menus: Disabled

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] ... not OK [ Documentation ]
Hide/show navigation items: Disabled
```

I am new to this and am under the impression that I just add those lines to the end of my config.in.php file. My file now looks like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma__users';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma__usergroups';

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma__navigationhiding';
```

But I still have the same problem as before. Also there are no tables with those names under phpmyadmin in the databases list on the left side. Do I need to create the tables for them? And if so, how do I know what to put in the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply run the script in examples/create_tables.sql (that is, within the examples folder of your main phpMyAdmin installation) to create the missing tables.

It should ignore the tables you already have created. You'll need to use the same table name in the configuration file as is used in the script, but looks like you're using the default which should work fine so no need to change anything there.

You can run the script by using the Import tab within phpMyAdmin. Click on the phpMyAdmin database ("pmadb", probably) and look for the "Import" tab. (If your local computer isn't the one running phpMyAdmin, you'll have to transfer the file locally first, use the UploadDir feature and copy the file to your UploadDir, or use the command-line tool).

Comment: So that added the tables that werent there but it put it under a subdirectory "pma" under the phpmyadmin db. so i have all the tables under the main db but also all the tables PLUS the three i needed under the new "pma" subdirectory. Also i still have the same issue. apparently phpmyadmin just updated again today so im going to try that and see what happens...